# How to create Criteria Builder query for joining three tables having One to One and Many to One entity relationship?

Tags: java, join, criteria

I want to create a criteria builder query for joining three tables. I've looked into internet but all the examples of three tables join have a different relationship than I want. So I have three tables having following structure:
[image: Table structure]

And the entity as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@Data
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEAD_ID")
    private Head head;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEES")
@Data
public class Employees {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
    private String empName;

    @Column(name = "RESUME")//clob
    private String resume;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private Department department;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACT")
@Data
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(unique = true, length = 36)
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "NUMBER")
    private Long number;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")//clob
    private String address;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private Department department;
}
```

Now I want to

> Get the contact of department in which an employee named Mike is
>   currently posted under the head has id=1234.

I have tried the following query

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Contact> criteria = builder.createQuery(Contact.class);
Root<Contact> contactRoot = criteria.from(Contact.class);
Root<Employees> employeesRoot = criteria.from(Employees.class);
//Join<Employees, Department> employeesDepartmentJoin = contactRoot.join("department", JoinType.INNER); With this statement#: Throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [empName] on this ManagedType [org.sample.something.Contact] exception.

Join<Employees, Department> employeesDepartmentJoin = employeesRoot.join("department", JoinType.INNER);
Join<Contact, Department> contactDepartmentJoin = contactRoot.join("department", JoinType.INNER);

List predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
predicates.add(builder.equal(employeesDepartmentJoin.get("head").get("id"), headID));
predicates.add(builder.equal(employeesDepartmentJoin.getParent().get("empName"), empName));
criteria.where(builder.and((Predicate[]) predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
criteria.select(contactRoot).distinct(true);
return getEm().createQuery(criteria).getResultList(); //Without statement#: Throws org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet exception.
```

The hibernate query which is generated during grammar exception is:

```
select distinct contact0_.id as id1_47_, contact0_.number as number_id9_47_, contact0_.city as city10_47_, contact0_.address as address10_47_, contact0_.department_id as department11_47_
from sample.contact contact0_ 
inner join sample.department department2_ on contact0_.department_id=department2_.id
cross join sample.employees employees1_ 
inner join sample.department department3_ on employees1_.department_id=department3_.id 
where department3_.head_id=? and employees1_.employee_name=?
```

Anyone who can put light on it will be helpful. Thanks.

**EDIT:** Updated code with new fields and StackTrace of SQLGrammarException(the first exception of "Unable to locate Attribute.." is thrown while evaluating only otherwise it throws same SQLGrammarException)

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74)
    at org.sample.something.dao.ContactDAO.getContactByHeadAndEmployeeName(ContactDAO.java:102)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505)
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:58)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
```

Comment: Your code contradicts your question: it has a ManyToOne between Contact and Department. And you're asking about an exception, but you're not posting the complete stack trace of the exception, which would allow us to know what and where the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry my bad. I have edited the code. thanks

Comment: And you're asking about an exception, but you're not posting the complete stack trace of the exception, which would allow us to know what and where the problem is.

Comment: The error is caused by some clob-related issue. I don't think it has anything to do with your query (except maybe by the distinct clause, because you can not use distinct when a clob is involved in Oracle, IIRC)

Comment: @JBNizet ok but however the native query works in the SQL developer; so how do I solve this problem in java?